# Does replicate-rewrite-db have any real world application?

Tags: mysql, replication, database-replication

I've been experimenting with master-master replication between two MySQL servers but with different database names and I've come accross a bit of a stumbling block.  It appears that although UPDATEs work correctly as expected, INSERTs do not.

While I would say that this is a bug or at least a problem with my setup, it appears that MySQL says that this is a feature ([here](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=53928) and [here](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=58919)).

If then, as MySQL say, it only works on the default database, then how can this setting have a practical real world purpose?

Am I missing something ?

---

For reference the relevant parts in my.cnf.  I've been testing this by doing inserts and updates from within phpMyAdmin if that makes any difference.

master

```
log-bin=mysql-bin
binlog_do_db=db1
```

slave

```
replicate-rewrite-db=db1->db2
replicate-wild-do-table=db2.table1
```

Comment: I provided an answer, but I will set up an actual environment tomorrow to recreate your test scenario and verify your situation.  If you also have time, please attempt using the standard mysql console and comparing between USE db1 and generic inserts vs. specifying the database name in your queries.  You should see a difference there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Replication-rewrite-db` usage is same as other replication options. Not only `Replication-rewrite-db` works on the default database, but these also: `replicate-do-db, replicate-ignore-db, binlog-do-db and binlog-ignore-db`. Refer [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/replication-options-slave.html) and [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/replication-options-binary-log.html).

There are real world purpose, else MySQL wouldn't have implemented this option. And it works only on default database [because](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/replication-options-slave.html)-

> The main reason for this “check just the default database” behavior is
>   that it is difficult from the statement alone to know whether it
>   should be replicated (for example, if you are using multiple-table
>   DELETE statements or multiple-table UPDATE statements that act across
>   multiple databases). It is also faster to check only the default
>   database rather than all databases if there is no need.

You should also know the replication rules. From [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/replication-rules-db-options.html).

I tested phpmyadmin by issuing `INSERT, DELETE and UPDATE` and noticed(By enabling `general_query_log`) that it issues `INIT DB 'db_name'`('Init DB' is logged for the `mysql_select_db()` API call).

For example:

```
Init DB sakila
1 Query INSERT INTO `sakila`.`actor_info` (`actor_id`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `film_info`) VALUES ('1235', 'abc', 'efg', NULL)
```

So ultimately the replication shouldn't break as phpmyadmin does it correctly by executing USE db before every query.

Comment: Thanks Ashwin, you're the first person to question how I was testing and you've made me realise where I was going wrong. Issuing sql commands via phpmyadmin does indeed work but the sql commands that phpmyadmin generate are of the form db1.table_name, so that was what was going wrong.  I've now run a few more tests and its looking good.

Answer (score 1):

I believe what they are referring there in the documentation, is that it is not going to translate specific database names for you, only databases set by USE.  What they mean by that is, if you were to execute something such as:

```
USE db1;
INSERT INTO table_name (x,y,z) VALUES (1,2,3);
```

It should do as you're expecting.

However, if you explicitly name a database in your query, it will not automatically translate that for you.  e.g.

```
INSERT INTO db1.table_name (x,y,z) VALUES (1,2,3);
```

It is quite possible that phpMyAdmin is translating your query to specify the database name, along with the table name.

EDIT:
While this does have practical purpose if you are in complete control of your query authoring across your entire system, you need to be extremely careful that you know what your queries are before they are run.  Some types of ORM systems or intermediaries will rewrite your queries for you to be explicit.  I would not suggest using this in production, especially when several teams are writing code that interfaces to your MySQL server.

Comment: So to get this to work you have to specify the database in every single sql query? Surely that's balmy? If MySQL knows what database to write to, then why can't the replication engine?

Comment: Hi Michael, while this probably works, without having authorship over every single query, it can't be guaranteed to work all of the time.  In which case it could very quickly lead to differences in the two databases.  Is there no way to get MySQL to simply prepend the currently selected database to the replication engine?

Answer (score 1):

I have a set up with a limited number of MySQL servers, two. One is production (PROD) and only used for production, the other is development and doubles as Disaster Recovery (DR) and for running longing queries.

To enable disaster recovery, the PROD server replicates to the DR using replication but without renaming this would end up with two databases on the same server with the same name.  So what I have is on production:

```
db_application
```

and on development I have two

```
db_application (which is used for development)
slave_application (which is used for DR)
```

Instead of using USE in every statement, I use the connection string to specify which database is the default and none of the statements include the database name. (i.e. **SELECT * FROM TABLE** rather than **SELECT * FROM DB.TABLE**)

This allows replication to work and to have a database on the development server with the same name as the production server. Which suits my needs but I appreciate others may not find this set up practical. This better suits having full control of the SQL but limited control of connection strings.

Comment: So you have replication running between two servers but with the same database name, i.e. db_application.  I've ended up having to resort to this situation too. However, my question was about using the replicate-rewrite-db statement to go between different database names. Sorry, no bounty here.

Comment: not quite. the replication is db_application => slave_application. The db_application on the DR box is the development instance, which is why I needed to use the replicate-rewrite-db (DR, as usual, was an after-thought)

Comment: Then that's exactly what I'm after, how is your my.cnf setup to handle this?

Comment: I can't access the server at the moment but it sounds like your config is fine but as Michael has highlighted it's a problem with the SQL statements used to INSERT data into the database. Rather than updates to the CNF, I needed updates to the SQL and connection strings.

Comment: Now you've confused me again :( As far as I'm aware to have INSERTs working over different table names, you need to specify the database name, as in "INSERT INTO db1.table_name (x,y,z) VALUES (1,2,3); ". Your answer implies that you've found another way of doing this: "none of the statements include the database name". But your latest comment contradicts this: " I needed updates to the SQL". Please could you clarify your strategy for me.

Comment: None of my statements reference the db name, and all statements access one db at a time. In my app each db has its own conn string (e.g. conn_db_audit to access db_audit only). The 'update' to the SQL was to remove any refs to the db in the statement. Instead of INSERT INTO db_audit.t_event VALUES (X, Y), the db_audit is inferred from the conn string (Database=db_audit;) and the SQL is INSERT INTO t_event VALUES (X, Y). This updates the PROD DB and doesn't 'confuse' the replication engine.

Comment: That makes more sense now, but does leave me wondering how your my.cnf is setup.  Out of curiosity, what do you use to connect to MySQL, the standard MySQL library, MySQLi, or PDO?

Comment: It's a .Net app, I'm using the .Net connector. I'll fetch you the values from the cng files in about four hours when I'm due onsite.

Answer (score 0):

I said it as a fundamental glitch and they put it as a featured request for the same issue.. which happened in binary logging ... http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=65837