# mysql_select_db vs use

Tags: php, mysql

I'm curious to know what functional differences there are between using `mysql_select_db($db)` and `mysql_query("USE $db")`.

I'm interested in this because it may well solve a long running issue I have with [MySQL replication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9843260/does-replicate-rewrite-db-have-any-real-world-application) over different databases.

Are both OK, or should the second one be avoided for some reason?

Thanks

p.s. please can we steer clear of discussion about the `mysql_*` functions being deprecated.

Comment: Do you do all your querys like [imagin back tick] `SELECT db_name.* FROM db_name.table WHERE db_name.col=value`?

Comment: exactly the same, as long the connection is the same they have the same effect

Comment: Both are fine. You can use any of them, imo.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone, no, most of our queries are of the format "Select * FROM table ...."

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem, Thanks, really constructive advice.  They're not currently deprecated just 'Discouraged'.  I'd love to use something else but I have inherited the codebase from someone else and changing the underlying connector is not something that is that easy. Hence, my request to steer clear of this subject.

Comment: @RobForrest: ok, you're right, it's not deprecated yet, but issuing `E_DEPRECATED` is very likely to be introduced in PHP5.5/5.6. You might want to [check this link](http://randomdrake.com/2011/08/02/php-developers-finally-deprecating-extmysql-in-favor-of-mysqli-or-pdo/) for some more info, and links to scripts to help with migrating

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As seen on [PHP.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-select-db.php), you can use either of them. A user commented regarding the same too:

> You can select MySQL database without using this function. Simply right after connecting to MySQL

```
<?php $connection = mysql_connect("dabatbasehost", "username", "password"); ?>
```

> perform this query:

```
<?php mysql_query("USE somedatabase", $connection); ?>
```

---

And in later comments, no one is rejecting the idea, I'm assuming that there will be no problems.

Comment: I'd prefer to go on something a little stronger than an assumption please.